# Trying to compute C to have an output input segment

Tags: c

Here is my code I am trying to print out info like a Scanner in Java. How can I do so in C?

```
int main(){

    char buffer[1000];
    FILE *pFile;

    pFile = fopen("randomnumbers.txt", "r");

    if(!pFile){
        printf("Error : Couldn't Read the File\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
{
    puts(buffer);
}
printf("Success Reading from File\n");

if(fclose(pFile) != 0)
    printf("Error : File Not Closed\n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: fread(buffer, 1, 1000, pFile);  will read 1000 bytes from the file and put them into buffer if that is what you're trying to do?

Comment: Use `fscanf`, or `fgets` with `sscanf`

Comment: The question looks too neat and clean. Why don't you mess up the indentation a little more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really hope this helps, this is how i could have done it.

int main(){

```
char buffer[1000];
```

//I think this means that you only expect there to be a maximum of 1,000
// characters per lines read.

```
FILE *pFile;



pFile = fopen("randomnumbers.txt", "r");


if(!pFile){

    printf("Error : Couldn't Read the File\n");

    return 1;

}

 }
```

// You can also read from a file using fscanf
    // You pass the file, data type to read and the buffer
    // to store it in. You can check for valid data because
    // fscanf() returns a number other then 1 if it isn't
    // a string

```
while(fscanf(pFile, "%s", buffer) == 1){

   // Puts outputs the string plus a newline.
    // Returns a nonnegative integer if it was successful
    // and EOF if there was an error

    puts(buffer);

}


printf("Success Reading from File\n");

// Closes the text file

if(fclose(pFile) != 0)
    printf("Error : File Not Closed\n");

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Replace with this:

```
int main(){

    char buffer[1001]; // i have added one byte because all strings are ending with zero byte

    FILE *pFile;




    pFile = fopen("randomnumbers.txt", "r");
    if(!pFile){
          printf("Error : Couldn't Read the File\n");
          return 1;
    }
    int bytesReaded = fread(
         buffer, // output buffer
         1, // char size is 1
         1000, // length of buffer - 1
         pFile // opened file
     );
    // Now you have readed the content of file
    // And check if file was readed successfully

   if(bytesReaded > 0){
        buffer[bytesReaded] = '\0'; // all strings in C are ended with zero byte
        // And now you can puts the content to console output
        puts(buffer);
   } else {
      // File not readed successfully or is empty
   }


    printf("Success Reading from File\n");

    if(fclose(pFile) != 0)
        printf("Error : File Not Closed\n");

    return 0;
}
```